# How to assign an index signature to a object's value?

Tags: typescript-typings

Giving the following code:

```
  export function objToStr(object: object): string {

    let str = [];

    for (let p in object) {
      if (object.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(object[p]))
      }
    }


    return str.join("&")
  }
```

I get the error from `object[p]`:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature. [7017]
```

I tried with

```
 encodeURIComponent((<any>object[p]))

 encodeURIComponent(object[p]: any)
```

But I still get the error. I find typing everything quite confusing, there is so much types out there.

If someone can tell me what Typescript wants from me there, it would help a lot, it's the last error message and then I'm done switching my code form JS to TS.

**EDIT**

I had to add `"noImplicitAny": true` to test the setting as I wasn't sure what is was doing and how the code would react to it.

Turning it to false I now get:

`Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. [2345]` for the part insite `str.push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error appears because you have `compilerOptions.noImplicitAny = true` at tsconfig.json. As error suggests, add *index signature* to `object` variable:

```
let object: { [index: string]: any } = {};
let str: string[] = [];
```

i.e. `any` will be specified explicit.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question to reflect the complete function as I forgot the first line. I also tried turning the option to false and now I got an even more confusing error. Could you include the solution to that too in your answer if you have time? (I'm taking notes here :))

Comment: @HypeWolf, probably `encodeURIComponent` returns `never`, show it's code.

Comment: It's a JS function: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp I took this function off the internet and it's working in regular JS

Comment: Where is exactly this error located? Try to change `object` variable name to something else to eliminate ambiguous with type.

Comment: Good idea! I replaced `object` with `obj`. The red underlined characters are `encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p])`

Comment: Try to declare `let str : string[] = [];`

Comment: How did you guess that? It works... I could never have figured this out. Thanks buddy!